# Laravel: Extra relation in a nested relationship

Tags: laravel, relationship

I have a classic nested relationship:

`User hasMany licences`

`Licence belongsTo User`
`Licence hasMany attestations`

`Attestation belongsTo Licence`
`Attestation hasMany vehicles`

`Vehicle belongsTo Attestation`

Now, for practical reason, I'd need to add an extra relationship with the lowest item in the hierarchy:

`Licence hasMany vehicles`

and optionaly:
`Vehicle belongsTo Licence`

I'd like to know if it possible and safe to do it that way and if there is no side effect.

Comment: use hasOneThrough, hasManyThrough https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#has-many-through

Comment: Which version of Laravel are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Laravel version 8.x you can try HasManyThrough, according to their documentation https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#has-many-through . In your case it would be something like this:

```
class Licence extends Model
{
    //...

    /**
     * Get all of the vehicles for the licence.
     */
    public function vehicles()
    {
        return $this->hasManyThrough(Vehicle::class, Attestation::class);
    }
}
```

BelongsTo does not work like this, you have to work with https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#has-one-through.

```
class Vehicle extends Model
{
    //...

    /**
     * Get all of the vehicles for the licence.
     */
    public function licence()
    {
        return $this->hasOneThrough(Licence::class, Attestation::class);
    }
}
```